# Combine data from multiple tables in a single XML Tag

Tags: sql-server, xml, join

I have two tables, TB1 - RndString and TB2 - Time

For example,

Values in TB1 are "I get up at ", "I sleep at ", "I have lunch at "

Values in TB2 are "7:00", "22:00", "13:00"

I want to combine the values of these tables into one xml file. 
Sample output is

```
<Data>
                <StringConcat>I Get up at 07:00 </StringConcat>
</Data>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT TB1.RndString+' '+CAST(TB2.Time AS varchar(5)) 
FROM TB1,TB2
FOR XML PATH ('StrConcat'),
ROOT ('Data')
```

Of course, this will result in a cross join of TB1 and TB2, but should give you the general idea.

Raj